# How to get Rows with error message in PostgresSQL during Batch Insertion?

Tags: python, oracle, postgresql

How to get Rows with errors in PostgresSQL Database like in Oracle executemany  Batcherror is used as: `cursor.executemany( sql_insert_query, data, batcherrors = True)` ?

(Using Python)

Comment: Welcome to the SO community. Please take the [tour] and review [ask]. Your question needs much more detail about the actual issue you have and what you are attempting. Not sure what you mean by "get rows with errors", but sounds like you may mean Oracle's "forall ... save exceptions ...". Is that the case?

Comment: I am saying as we do in Oracle : https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/efficient-and-scalable-batch-statement-execution-in-python-cx_oracle                                cursor.executemany("""
        insert into ChildTable (ChildId, ParentId, Description)
        values (:1, :2, :3)""", data, batcherrors = True)
for errorObj in cursor.getbatcherrors():
    print("Row", errorObj.offset, "has error", errorObj.message)    What is the way to to get Batch error rows number with error message?

Comment: In PostgresSQL.

Comment: Please, Can anyone help in this issue?

Comment: I Hope the question is clear now, if still any doubt just comment it here. Waiting for someone's reply to this issue.